# What is the maximum linux installation size?

Tags: linux, system-installation, repository, distributions

Let's say that I install every package avaible for a given linux distribution, how big would it be?

Obviously that size would depend on distribution and package choices, also there's no theorical limit if we sum every software avaible on github plus whatever software be developable.

For this sake let's consider only official packages from main, contribution and extra repositories.

Btw how functional that installation would be?

Comment: If you don't give a reason for asking this, this question isn't very useful. See https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: It's difficult to respond to your question without knowing which distribution or use case you're referring to. You need to be more specific.

Comment: how long is a piece of string?

Comment: @A.B I need to know in order to allocate enough space for a system partition.

Comment: @cas between 1 and inf bytes

Comment: To plan for the future: use LVM. Then size is easier to manage.

Answer (score 4):

Let’s consider Debian unstable, as a proxy for “large distribution” (it’s larger than any release of Debian). The sum of the installed sizes of all available packages on `amd64` can be obtained as follows:

```
$ awk '/Installed-Size:/ { sum += $2 } END { print sum }' /var/lib/apt/lists/deb.debian.org_*unstable*amd64_Packages
387545199
```

The size is given in kibibytes, so this equals 369.6 GiB.

Note that this is a theoretical maximum: it is impossible to install all available packages simultaneously, because some packages conflict with each other. For example, only one mail server can be installed at once.

A valid, maximal installation of Debian should still be usable, although it will result in running a large number of services.

The size can be inflated by considering debug packages; installing all the `main` debug packages takes an additional 91.5 GiB.